# Function using i in its own loop, and a sub function loop - var behaving like let?

Tags: javascript

I was doing a test, with `var i` used in a loop in a parent function and a subfunction.

This is my code:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   var gArr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

   function ix(a) {
    for (var i = 0; i < gArr.length; i++) {
     document.body.innerHTML += '<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;i from ix: ' + i;
     if (gArr[i] == a) {
      return a;
     }
    }
   }

   function blah(newAdds) {

    for (var i = 0; i < newAdds.length; i++) {
     document.body.innerHTML += '<br>i from blah: ' + i;
     var cEntry = ix(newAdds[i]);
     document.body.innerHTML += '<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;i from blah post ix: ' + i;
     if (!cEntry) {
      gArr.push(newAdds[i]);
     }
    }

   }

   window.onload = blah.bind(null, ['d', 'e']);
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

The output of this code is this:

```
i from blah: 0
     i from ix: 0
     i from ix: 1
     i from ix: 2
  i from blah post ix: 0
i from blah: 1
     i from ix: 0
     i from ix: 1
     i from ix: 2
     i from ix: 3
  i from blah post ix: 1
```

Because the function `ix` also uses `var i` I was expecting that the `i from blah post ix` would be overwritten to be the final `i` value from `ix` which is `3` in the above case. However it is not.

Is this expected behavior? I thought `let` was supposed to give us this kind of behavior not `var`?

Comment: [RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variable_scope)

Comment: `var` variables are limited to their containing function, therefore two `i`'s in your functions are distinct.

Comment: @hindmost: [STFU](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) ;)

Comment: Thanks very much @georg - I even realized something new in this experiement. If I globally declare `var i` and then in my functions I use a `var i`, I can set `i` in this function to whatever and the global `i` will be unaffected, this amazing. Thanks!

Comment: I wrote this new example with global i here - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/d7cbeed8106991e83359 - it prints the global i before and after blah and its amazing it is unchanged. Even though the `var i` within functions are "contained" within the global scope. I can't believe I didn't know this for so long haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're redeclaring the `var i`

If you declare it once at the top then I think it does what you mean (I think)

See snippet below

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   var gArr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
                        var i; /* <-- declare it here */
   function ix(a) {
    for (i = 0; i < gArr.length; i++) {
     document.body.innerHTML += '<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;i from ix: ' + i;
     if (gArr[i] == a) {
      return a;
     }
    }
   }

   function blah(newAdds) {

    for (i = 0; i < newAdds.length; i++) {
     document.body.innerHTML += '<br>i from blah: ' + i;
     var cEntry = ix(newAdds[i]);
     document.body.innerHTML += '<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;i from blah post ix: ' + i;
     if (!cEntry) {
      gArr.push(newAdds[i]);
     }
    }

   }

   window.onload = blah.bind(null, ['d', 'e']);
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh wow very interesting, yep it behaves the way I was expcting if we use `for (i=0; ....` in `ix()` rather then `for (var i=0; ....`, do you know why this is?

Comment: Ah wait I see you made it global, so the way it works is obvious.

Comment: So it seems all variables with a function are automatically closed off. Even if I defined a `var i` inside the function it wouldn't affect the global value it will just be like a sort of closure. Interesting this is nice. It avoid some major bugs.

Comment: Exactly that - declare inside and it stays inside

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript scopes at the function level**

The reason the value gets reset is because they are declared in two different functions, see the following for example:

```
var f = function(){ 
    var i="12"; 
    console.log(i);
    var fn2 = function(){ 
        var i="13"; 
        console.log(i);
    }; 
    fn2(); 
    console.log(i); 
};
```

The result will be

```
 12
 13
 12
```

Because the variable is scoping at the function level the internal variable `i` is not the same as the one in the parent function.

Comment: Thanks very much @konkked !